# How to parse nested json objects with Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

This JSON is created from an ASP.NET Dictionary filled with DataSet objects, with the Newtonsoft parser. How can I parse this on the client with Jquery?

Or, is there a better way to jsonize my datasets?

```
{
    "Object1": {
        "Table": [
            {
                "somekey": "b"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Object2": {
        "Table": [
            {
                "somekey": "880",
                "somekey": "x"
            },
            {
                "somekey": "88"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: whay  do you want do with it?How do you want to store it?

Comment: I want to iterate the json object and read certain values under each object node. Then I plan to store the json string on the client with localstorage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things.

1. Use Jquery's .parseJSON() method.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

```
var parsedJsonObject = jQuery.parseJSON(yourJSONResponseFromServer);
```

1. Change the output of your JSON from the server to look like this. Notice the outermost element is NOT a single massive JSON object as defined by {}, but instead is an array of anonymous objects [].

```
[
    {
        "Table": [
            {
                "somekey": "b"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Table": [
            {
                "somekey": "880",
                "somekey": "x"
            },
            {
                "somekey": "88"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The way you were doing it previously you'd have to do.

```
var parsedJsonObject = jQuery.parseJSON(yourJSONResponseFromServer);

parsedJsonObject.Object1.table[indexYouWantToAccess];
parsedJsonObject.Object2.table[indexYouWantToAccess];
parsedJsonObject.Object3.table[indexYouWantToAccess];
```

But if you reformat it with the [] on the outside you can do this.

```
var parsedJsonObject = jQuery.parseJSON(yourJSONResponseFromServer);

for (var i=0; i < parsedJsonObject.length; i++) {
    parsedJsonObject[i].table[indexYouWantToAccess];
}
```

Comment: I took your advice and changed my design from using datasets, to using datatables held in a Dictionary object. This gives me named main nodes which I can easily iterate. I think creating json formatted strings from complex object models are easier than doing the reverse, so I will do things as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
var array=[];

for(var i=0;i<json.length;i++)//json is the object from server
{//object in Dictionary
array.push(json[i]);//push any object to array
//if you want run any table
for(var j=0;j<json[i].length;j++)
{//table in object

var table =json[i][j]//table

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.parse()

e.g.

```
JSON.parse(jQuery(data).text());
```

where 'data' is either xml/text returned via an AJAX request

Comment: But how do I iterate over the parsed object?